# Using gl-transitions in a simple html page

Tags: javascript, html, animation, webgl, transition

How can I use https://gl-transitions.com/ shaders in a static HTML page?

I need a simple example for animating two images.

Comment: You can do that by reading the documentation on the page you linked and following it's steps one by one.

Comment: @cloned I don't see any documentation about static html pages. I don't want to use npm packages and build tools.

Comment: Please read the **complete** documentation, you can either use npm package or use it directly.

Comment: @cloned Excuse me, can you write a code snippet that can be run in the browser? I don't understand how to use the package in browser...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gl-transitions library without NPM by embeding their code in your page:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gl-transitions@1/gl-transitions.js"></script>
```

This will load the library from their CDN to make it available in your static web page.